# What is the correct package hierarchy for @Aspect classes and @ControllerAdvice classes?

Tags: spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

**Problem Details**
I`m currently implementing two classes in my Spring Boot, Spring MVC project.

First:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {
// body not relevant to this problem
}
```

Second:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
// body not relevant to this problem
}
```

The current project package hierarchy looks like this.
Hierarchy:

```
com.example
├── aspect
│   └── MyAspect.java
├── advice
│   └── GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler.java
```

**Problem**
I`m not sure if this is the correct package hierarchy.

**Possible Solution**
Since both advice and aspect are Spring AOP features, should I place these two packages in one base package called 'aop'?

A possible solution for my project package hierarchy.
Hierarchy:

```
com.example
└── aop
    ├── aspect
    │   └── MyAspect.java
    │
    └── advice
        └── GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler.java
```

Please, correct me if I`m wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest sticking to the first approach, where you have a package based on the type of components - Repository/Controller/Service..

```
com.example
├── aspect
│   └── MyAspect.java
├── advice
│   └── GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler.java
```

First, AOP means Aspect-Oriented Programming, noting component related

Second, If you check Spring `ControllerAdvice` for the reference, you will notice that it doesn't come from a specific `aop` related package

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
```

When I personally have concerns about such stuff, I always prefer to check Java libraries or some other libraries for the reference

Comment: Hi! You are right; my bad. To clarify: I said ControllerAdvice is a Spring AOP feature because it uses a somewhat similar concept by intercepting and altering the return values of controller methods. Still, it is not directly a part of the Spring AOP module. Therefore I should stick to my first approach and not group different packages into one general. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the package hierarchy should be consistent with the rest of the projects, with separation of responsibilities, clean definitions...

How much granularity do you want to give it? It depends on each one but I would go for option one.

I think (without seeing the rest of the project) that you will have something like this:

```
com.example
├── aspect
│   └── MyAspect.java
├── advice
│   └── GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler.java
├── service
│   └── MySErvice.java
├── controller
│   └── MyController.java
├── repository
│   └── MyRepository.java
...
```